# Scapy extract IP address with no repetitions

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to extract the destination IP address then save this in a dictionary but i only want it once

Input

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = rdpcap('example.pcap')

test = ""
for pkt in pkts:
    temp = pkt.sprintf("%IP.dst%",)
    test = test + temp

print(test)
```

Currently my output is like this

```
??,????,????,????,??0.0.0.0,255.255.255.255192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2380.0.0.0,255.255.255.255192.168.1.1,192.168.1.238192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2380.0.0.0,255.255.255.255192.168.1.1,192.168.1.238??,????,????,????,????,??192.168.1.238,192.168.1.1192.168.1.1,192.168.1.238192.168.1.238,89.30.121.15089.30.121.150,192.168.1.238192.168.1.238,89.30.121.150192.168.1.238,89.30.121.15089.30.121.150,192.168.1.238192.168.1.238,89.30.121.150192.16
```

What I want is the output to look like this and I want the destination IP address only with no repeats

```
89.30.121.150
198.50.110.244
89.30.121.14
89.30.121.23
```

What I do get in the output is a massive list of IP addresses instead I only want the destination IP address but only ONCE(no repetitions) not for each packet

I have also tried this but this freezes?

```
def print_summary(pkt):
    if IP in pkt:
        ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
    print(ip_dst)

sniff(offline=pkts, filter="ip",prn=print_summary)
```

Can anyone think of a quicker solution to extract IP addresses from larger PCAP files using Scapy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put in dictionary you should use dictionary.

You getting repeated value because you are not saving it into python dict.

Here is one way to keep `src-->dest` ip without repeating by modifying your code:

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = rdpcap('example.pcap')

dic = {}
for pkt in pkts:
    temp = pkt.sprintf("%IP.dst%")
    dic[temp] = 1

for ip in dic.keys():
    print(ip)
```

output:

```
192.168.1.1
192.37.115.0
192.168.1.2
212.242.33.35
192.168.1.251
147.137.21.94
147.137.21.122
147.234.1.253
```

One of the fastest method is:

```
from scapy.all import *

IP.payload_guess = []

ips = set(p[IP].dst for p in PcapReader('example.pcap') if IP in p)

for ip in ips:
    print(ip)
```

Comment: I have edited my question....I only want the destination IP address and also I only wanted to save it once (no repetitions)

Comment: No sorry it doesnt work i get this error     print(*dic.keys(),sep='\n')
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This works but takes too long even to process a 300KB pcap file do you know of any other way of doing this quicker

Comment: Thanks I will try this...also do you know how I can add up the packet length for each IP address in Scapy the packet length can be print len(pkt)

Comment: if problem is solved, accept the answer.. I will try that later thanks